# HttpWebRequest works with only asmx or wsdl also

Tags: vb.net, wsdl, asmx

HttpWebRequest works with only asmx or wsdl also ?

https://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/e-FilingWS/ditws/Get26asInfo.wsdl
can b used ? with following data for - HttpWebRequest

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:v="http://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/ditws/tds/v_1_0">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<v:getTDSDetails>
<v:LoginInfo>
<v:userName>xxxxxxxxxx</v:userName>
<v:password>xxxxxxxxxx</v:password>
</v:LoginInfo>
<v:ClientInfo>
<v:pan>xxxxxxxxxx</v:pan>
<v:dob>xxxxxxxxxx</v:dob>
<v:assessmentYear>xxxxxxxxxx</v:assessmentYear>
</v:ClientInfo>
</v:getTDSDetails>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

if not, how to get Response Envelope xml while consuming wsdl(service reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WSDL exists as a framework to tell external entities how to consume the web service - you should send all actual web service requests to the ASMX file to ensure they are handled properly.

[See the W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl)

Comment: we dont have asmx, whether HttpWebRequest can be used with wsdl link?

Comment: Have you tried consuming the WSDL directly using Visual Studio's 'Add Web Reference' function? That then provides an object you can call the web service methods from.

Comment: directly its working, but we need response envelop, so we tried using HttpWebRequest

Comment: The fact remains that you cannot send requests to a WSDL as if it were a web service. You'll need to locate the actual service URL that handles the calls and send your HttpWebRequests to that.

Comment: How to locate the service URL from wsdl?

Comment: Perhaps ask the provider of the service? (I'm assuming the service is not something you've developed yourself)